# Passing Dropdown list Python FLask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Below my html code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <select class="form-control">
      {% for e in get %}
        <option value=" {{ e }} ">{{ e }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

model.py code

```
from dbconnection import connection
def getall():
try:
    c, conn = connection()
    DICT = c.execute('SELECT prog_name FROM programming_language')
    DICT = c.fetchall()
    return DICT
except Exception as e:
    return (str(e))
```

init.py code

```
from model import getall
DICT = getall()
@app.route('/')

def homepage():
    return render_template("main.html", get = DICT)
```

it gives me results like this includes open and close parenthesis, comma and apostrophe, it looks like generate itself instead of this python it give me this ('python',) i aims this python.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CcZW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parentheses and commas are the way your database query is returning results: each returned record is being returned as a tuple with only one value.

Try adding this line to your `getall()` function:

```
    (...)

    DICT = c.fetchall()
    return [row[0] for row in DICT if len(row) >= 1]
```